# Python(html) get data from dynamically changing div/span with bf4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I need to get the real time BTC from https://cryptowat.ch/ but when the program run by 5 times it will stop and when i check the site im banned cuz the lot of request..
How can i get the data without refreshing the whole site with Python?

Here is the code:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def btc():
    r= requests.get("https://cryptowat.ch/")

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    number = soup.find_all('a',{'class':'_1roDdymkPS2zplXEDcBm0L _3z3AqahoD2pN2R7vFue-0o pointer'})[1].find("span").text
    #btc = [span.text for span in number]
    return number
"""while True:
    print("A jelenlegi BTC ár : "+str(bekero))"""


while True:
    print("A jelenlegi BTC ár : "+str(btc()))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: You should use proxies and do each request with unique proxies.

Comment: There is no way to do this with selenium or scrapy?

Comment: With selenium possibly. Not with scraping the html through requests though like BeautifulSoup (I assume scrapy is similar although I’m not very familiar with it). It’s possible that there is a request which returns just the bitcoin value which has softer ban rates and may be possible to use requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use selenium with chrome webdriver (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)

Basically, what you'll be doing (using python code) is open a chrome window, direct it to a certain website, interact with the webpage if you want and then read the page content and pass it to BS4.

Note that the requests library does not load dynamic content.

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

source = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html").get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

And then pass the page source to BS4